# HighCharts - Exibir tooltip em coluna igual a 0 ou sem valor

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Olá!

A um tempo implementei o Highcharts no Framework em minha empresa, e posso dizer que estamos super satisfeitos com o mesmo. Porém estamos com um problema que não sabemos como resolver.

Nos gráficos de coluna, quando uma coluna tem o seu valor igual a zero não é exibida nenhuma informação visual disto, somente a coluna que é omitida. Eu gostaria que fosse exibido o tooltip quando o usuário passasse o mouse sobre o espaço da coluna onde o valor é igual a 0.

Vejam o fiddle abaixo onde é gerado um gráfico de barras com diversas colunas com valor igual a 0, ou sem valor.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mayconfsbrito/EJK4e/8/)

Vocês poderiam me dar uma dica de como fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido inserindo o atributo `minPointLength` na montagem do meu gráfico.

Veja o exemplo no Fiddle abaixo:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EJK4e/12/)